# How do I express a drastic change in mindset?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

If I previously thought something, but an experience caused me to change  my mindset completely, what would be a good way to express that in writing?

I've already said that it "rewrote every preset notion I had", but what is another way of putting this?

Thank you

Comment: [Paradigm shift](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/paradigm-shift) describes the change in thinking, but does not adequately express the presence of a triggering event.   There is another, better phrase that is not coming to me just now.

Comment: [Seismic shift](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seismic%20shift) is also often used to denote a large change in attitude or thinking, where the triggering event is a metaphorical earthquake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often described as a [*Damascene*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=define+damascene&oq=define+damascene) moment or Damascene conversion.

This derives from the biblical story of Saul who, on the road to Damascus saw a vision that caused him to convert to Christianity - becoming St.Paul.

The story relates that one single event caused a complete change in Saul's character and beliefs.  As you put in your question, rewriting all his preset notions.